# Converting string to binary in Java

Tags: java, binary

I'm a new programmer and I'm trying to write a program that takes a binary number as input.  It first determines if it is a binary number, and then if it is, counts how many 1's are in it then displays the amount.  Right now it rejects all of my numbers.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String binary;
int count = 0;
System.out.print( "Enter your binary number: ");
binary = scan.nextLine( );

for ( int i = 0; i <= binary.length()-1; i++){
    char c = binary.charAt(i);

    while ((c != '1') || (c != '0')){
        System.out.println( "Invalid Number try again" );
        System.out.println("Enter your binary number: ");
        binary = scan.nextLine();
    }
    if ( c == '1')
        count++;
}
System.out.println("The number of 1s are: "+count);
```

Comment: What language?  Looks like Java.  You should tag the language or at least mention it in the question.

Comment: I apologize it is Java

Answer (score 2):

Your while condition checks that the char is not equal to 1 or not equal to 0. If you think about it, this must always be false.

e.g. if the input char being considered is 1, this will evaluate to FALSE OR TRUE, and hence be TRUE. If the input char is 0, it will evaluate to TRUE OR FALSE, which again is TRUE.

So change the condition to check the char is not 1 AND not 0.

Comment: Thank you i didnt even see that it was as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` condition is logically incorrect.  Right now, you're checking to see if a character is either 'not 1' or 'not 0'.  All numbers are either not 1 or not 0.

If you want to exclude any characters which are neither 1 nor 0, you need to write

`while ( ( c != '1' ) && ( c != '0' ) )`

You should study some predicate logic or discrete structures.  This will help build your logical chops.